# Determine how much memory allocated for individual objects?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management

I can't find how to determine how much memory is in use by individual objects.

Using Xcode's visual memory debugger, the memory shown on the right side (circled red) is not how much memory the object is actually using.

[image]

Xcode allocation instruments seems to only show the entire heap and memory used by individual allocations, not objects as a whole.

Am I missing something? Is there anyway to see how much aggregated memory is used by individual objects?

Comment: You need to use instruments in xcode to find the same. https://www.raywenderlich.com/166125/instruments-tutorial-swift-getting-started

Comment: Thanks, but like I said, I don't see anywhere in Instruments that show aggregate memory use per object. Am I missing something?

Comment: By aggregate, you mean the object and any objects it references? What if those references are shared (i.e. what if two object both hold a strong reference to the same third object)?

Comment: I'd be happy if I could see the memory footprint for either the objects owned (along with the Malloc stack) by the object or even with weak references. It would be super helpful if I could see some kind of visualization of how big objects are.